# Issue on read_file using a while loop in Bash/sh

Tags: bash, sh

Does anyone know why after the first iteration I am out of the while loop here ? It used to work like yesterday!! (Same input file containing many lines, no new-lines)

```
#!/bin/sh
FLAGS_IN=MY_TEXT_FILE_CONTAINING_LOTS_OF_LINE

while read  BENCHMARK DATASET  CF
do
    echo "$BENCHMARK"
    echo "$DATASET"
    echo "$CF"
    N=$((N + 1))    

cd $tmp    
echo "**********************************************************"
            GCC_OPT="-O3"
            OPT_FLAGS=$CF
###### do sth



tmp=$PWD
done <  $FLAGS_IN

exit 0
```

debugging, I am sure the scripts work till the end of the loop pretty fine.

Comment: an empty value for the var `tmp` will the evaluate as a `cd` cmd without an argument, and send your script to you home dir.  You don't include in your code anything like `tmp=/tmp/dir` so we can't be sure what is happening. Why do you need a `cd $tmp` after reading each line? Otherwise, if it used to work and it doesn't work today, AND if you **really** didn't make any changes to the script, or ftp it from MSWindows to Linux, then it must be your data file. Use a text editor with a binary mode to see what is after the first line. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, tnx for reply. actually i have used this `tmp` somewhere in the begining of while cuz inside I am moving around some directories, that's why at the end I would like to go back where I was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#do sth` apparently contains a command that reads from standard input, so the next time the `read` executes, the end of the stream is reached. Pick a file handle you aren't using (3 is probably safe), and use that for your while loop:

```
while read BENCHMARK DATASET CF <&3
do
    # ...
done 3< $FLAGS_IN
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it took like an hour of mine, was totally out of idea what was happening, this file handle is working for me now